# How to calculate subtotal to specific row number in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table like follows. id is sequential number and they order ascending.

```
id score  name
1  10     A
2  20     B
3  30     C
4  40     D
```

I would like to calculate subtotal by using specific variable for example `3`
in conditioning `id<=3` I tried following , but a little complecated,and couldn't achieved.

```
          SUM( 
                CASE 
                    WHEN main.id <= 3
                        THEN main.score
                    ELSE 0 
                    END
            ) AS subtotal
           From main
```

My desired result is like follows. Are there any smarter ways to achieve this?

```
id subtotal name 
3  60    C
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/qnGLVGBF):

```
CREATE TABLE scores (
  id INTEGER,
  score INTEGER,
  name TEXT
);

INSERT INTO scores (id, score, name)
VALUES
  (1, 10, 'A'),
  (2, 20, 'B'),
  (3, 30, 'C'),
  (4, 40, 'D');

SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN id = 3 THEN id ELSE NULL END) AS id
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN id <= 3 THEN score ELSE 0 END) AS subtotal
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN id = 3 THEN name ELSE NULL END) AS name
From scores;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you aggregate your data and you don't limit this to `WHERE main.id <= 3`, then your approach is the typical way to achieve the result. It is called conditional aggregation. In standard SQL and PostgreSQL, too, you can get this more readable with:

```
SUM(main.score) FILTER (WHERE main.id <= 3)
```

or with the nulls replaced by zero as in your original expression:

```
SUM(COALESCE(main.score, 0)) FILTER (WHERE main.id <= 3)
```

Most DBMS don't support the `FILTER` clause yet. This is why most conditional aggregation examples on the Internet use `CASE` expressions.